# Error installing Visual Studio Tools for Tizen

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm attempting to follow the installation steps [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen) to install Visual Studio Tools for Tizen.

In step 4, I select a local folder e.g. C:\User\Username\AppData\Roaming\Samsung\tizen-studio

However, I receive an error:

```
Baseline SDK Installer is detected on
C:\User\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\Baseline_Tizen_Studio_windows-64.exe, but it can be an incomplete file.

Do you want to use an existing file anyway?
```

If I select yes or no, I get the following error:

```
Failed to install Tizen tools: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: try again. Message can indicate corrupt download or incomplete download.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've tried multiple times.

Comment: maybe it requires Windows 10.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That is what I'm assuming however it's not listed under the 'Prerequisites' on the official page - https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen

Comment: [Tizen Studio requires 10](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites#system), so maybe the VS tools also.